# Creating a box inside of git bash

Tags: node.js, git-bash, console.log

I am in the process of making a layout for a text based game in git bash using node(personal project). I have not been able to find anything pertaining to drawing a concrete block (eg: large rectangle) to hold my content in. The only thing I can think of is console.log(), but I am positive that there has to be better options out there. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: my apologies Toby, Im new to the whole asking thing, as well as im still in the psuedo-coding phase. I cant show code because as far as getting anything up, the only thing i can think of is the console.log("-----------"); so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using node then [terminal-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-kit) is probably someting like what you're looking for? Take a walk through [this tutorial too.](http://blog.soulserv.net/terminal-friendly-application-with-node-js/)

Comment: this definitely looks useful, I will definitely incorporate it and edit the post with any updates, thank you.